# Ratio test, Root test, and Divergence test related.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

(I) Ratio test: If the result is smaller than 1 then the sum is convergent, and if the sum is larger than 1 then the sum is divergent, and that got me thinking if negative infinity (smaller than 1) and positive infinity (larger than 1) are convergent and divergent, respectively. (And I understand that infinity is not a number, but still isn't negative infinity smaller than one? Or have I gone bananas?)

(II) Root test: If the result is smaller than 1 then the sum is (absolutely) convergent, but if the result is larger than 1 or equal to infinity then the sum is divergent. What kind of infinity do they mean in this case (Root test)?

(III) Divergence test: If the limit is not equal to zero, then the sum will diverge (and I understand that if it does equal zero then it can still be divergent, but anyway). Now, what I want to know is does this include infinity, be it negative or positive infinity, or am I missing something here?

Short note, most of the exercises I am required to do require detailed explanations and even if you do the whole calculations correctly but your explanation is wrong then the whole thing is considered wrong. Therefore, I want to actually know what I am doing, thank you! Also, please use (I)-(III) when explaining a specific test so I know which you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I) You need the *absolute value* of the limit result to be less than 1, so if your limit is $\pm\infty$ you will get a divergent series.

(II) You can think of any value greater than 1 as good enough to prove divergence.  Any "kind of infinity" will do.  Once again, absolute value applies here.

---

The takeaway from ratio and root tests is threefold:

1. $|\text{Limit}|<1\Longrightarrow\text{series converges absolutely}$
2. $|\text{Limit}|>1\Longrightarrow\text{series diverges}$
3. $|\text{Limit}|=1\Longrightarrow\text{test is inconclusive, so use another test for convergence!}$

---

(III) If the limit of the general term is not zero, the series diverges.  **If the limit is zero, the test is inconclusive!** Be careful that you do not use the converse of this statement, because the converse is not true.

Examples:

- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{n+1}$ diverges since $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}=1\ne0.$
- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2}{n+1}$ diverges since
  $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}=\infty\ne0.$
- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n+1}$ has $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}=0$ which means we do not know if the series converges or diverges unless we use another test.